# Batch script ignores %ERRORLEVEL% or using previously set one

Tags: batch-file, process, errorlevel

I wrote a batch script to find out if a specific process runs on a computer:

```
    for /f %%a in (computers.txt) do (
        PsList.exe \\%%a -e "process" > result.txt
        Find /i "found" < result.txt
        IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" echo %%a >> Computers_without_process.csv
)
```

I did `Find /i "found" < result.txt` because if the process is not found it returns: "process ... was not found on computername"

if the process is found it returns it's information. and the string "found" isnt there.

I tried just about anything.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion    
for /f %%a in (computers.txt) do (
        PsList.exe \\%%a -e "process" > result.txt
        Find /i "found" < result.txt
        IF "!ERRORLEVEL!" == "0" echo %%a >> Computers_without_process.csv
)
```

or you can use [conditional execution](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) (and [pipes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion    
for /f %%a in (computers.txt) do (
        PsList.exe \\%%a -e "process" | Find /i "found" >nul 2>nul && (
           echo %%a >> Computers_without_process.csv
         )
)
```